# Can I use docker container name as hostname in env variable?

Tags: docker

I have created a MySQL container with the following properties:

```
--hostname=localmysql
--name=local
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=master
```

Is it possible to use the MySQL running container **local** as the host name inside another docker instance's env variable? So it will be like:

```
docker run -e DB_HOST=local --name=node_image custom_node_image:latest
```

Comment: Yes it will be possible if you run the through the docker command and let them run on the default docker bridge. So yes it should work